# Empty class to use with LINQtoCSV - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, linqtocsv

I have the following in C# and I'm trying to convert it to vb.net.

```
   internal class MyDataRow : List<DataRowItem>, IDataRow
{

}
```

The rest of the code I've managed to convert myself it's just the empty class that I'm struggling with. This is so I can read in files with any columns and display them.

Edit:

Looking at the comment given and online I've got to the following:

```
Class MyDataRow
Inherits List(Of DataRowItem)
Implements IDataRow
End Class
```

I'm getting an error on the implements section.

This gives the following errors:

[image]

Comment: That's not an empty class. It's a class that inherits from List<DataRowItem> and implements IDataRow. Use the equivalent VB.NET syntax. Have you tried using the `Inherits` keyword?

Comment: I think you are not familiar with the `interface` concept, take a look at it in [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/)

Comment: Unless `MyDataRow` is an *abstract* or *partial* class, this C# code can't compile. Is that the *actual* declaration? No missing modifiers like `abstract` or `partial`? Does the source project compile in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to convert this class, you can use below codes:

```
Friend Class MyDataRow
    Inherits List(Of DataRowItem)
    Implements IDataRow
End Class
```

And you have to implement `IDataRow` interface methods as well